# How to detect https traffic with iptables u32 module?

Tags: 14.04, iptables, https

How would I detect http traffic through u32 module of iptables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to tell from outside what's going on inside a TLS connection. TLS is the [Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) protocol that wraps HTTP connections to turn them into HTTPS connection. This, i. e. privacy, is one of the three key features of TLS.

There are some methods to intercept the TLS connection and terminate it at the "connection inspector" but those require self-signed certificates in the client applications and defeat the security of TLS almost entirely.

Comment: David, If this is true any idea how sslh is able to do that?
Look out for is_tls_protocol in this file
https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh/blob/f451cc8bed7a8673c9710f628f7fab5dbdfe7866/probe.c

Comment: @Mysticmonk: If you look at the code it only detects if a data stream looks like a TLS session handshake. It cannot tell what kind of data and thus protocol type is wrapped inside the TLS session.